# Frame by frame animation using OpenGL and SDL

Tags: c, opengl, animation, sdl-2

I am working in a game project that features a large amout of assets. The character animations are very detailed and that require a lot of frames to happen.

At first, I created large spritesheets containing all the animations for a specific character. It was working well on my PC but when I tested it on an Android tablet, I noticed it ecceeded the maximum texture dimension of its GPU. My solution was to break down the big spritesheet into individual frames (the worst case is 180 frames) and upload them individually to the GPU. Things now seem to be working everywhere I need it to work.

Right now, the largest animation I have been working with is a character with 180 frames with 407x725 pixels of width and height. However, as I couldn't find any orientation on the web regarding how to properly render 2D animations using OpenGL, I would like to ask if there is a problem with this approach. Is there a maximum number of textures that can be uploaded to the GPU? Can I exceed the amout of RAM of the GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient method for the GPU is to pass the entire sprite sheet to opengl as a single texture, and select which frame you want by adjusting the texture coordinates when you draw. You should also pack the sprites into, ideally, a square texture. Reducing the overall amount of memory used by the GPU is very good for performance esp. on phones and tablets.

You want to avoid if possible frequently changing which texture is bound. Ideally you want to bind a single texture and then render bits and pieces of it to the screen until you don't need it anymore, then bind a different texture and continue.

The reason for this is that the GPU will try hard to optimize the operation of the pipeline it creates to handle the geometry you feed it, and the shaders you select. But when you make big changes to the configuration like changing what texture is bound or what shader is bound, that's necessarily going to be somewhat opaque to optimization. Feeding it more vertices and texture coordinates at a time is better because they basically can all get done in a batch without unloading and reloading resources etc.

However depending what cards you are targetting, you should keep in mind that there may be a maximum of 8192 x 8192 size of textures or something like this. So depending on what assets you have you may be forced to split them up across several textures.